# If we pass the kzalloc function size argument value is 0 then what happen?

Tags: linux-kernel

Please, tell any one in detaile description.

Comment: static __always_inline void *kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
 struct kmem_cache *cachep;
 void *ret;

 if (__builtin_constant_p(size)) {
  int i = 0;

  if (!size)
   return ZERO_SIZE_PTR;
....

Answer (score 1):

You will get a non-null result, but any attempt to write to the result will fault. Multiple calls will all be returned the same value.

See http://lwn.net/Articles/236920 for more, and in future please try Googling first.